# <g:select > key has json data --> output in gsp garbage

Tags: json, grails, gsp

I'm trying to fill select element with . List has three items with one of them is json data. When gsp page is rendreded this is what is in html:

```
<option a":"aa11","b":"bb33","cc":"cc44"}"="" value="{">label </option>
```

Is this a bug in Grails 2.0.4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape HTML characters in `optionKey`

Example :

```
<g:select optionKey="id" optionKey="${{it.toString().encodeAsHTML()}}" name="book.title" from="${bookList}" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. But in general shouldn't the g:select tag take care of encoding to html ?

Comment: GSPs can not know if you want to include directly or escaped when displaying a String.